# ORA-20000: Oracle Text error: DRG-10599: column is not indexed

Tags: c#, oracle, indexing, visual-studio-2015, contains

Hello I cant really make this sql workin because error column is not indexed (when i was using just like "=" it was all right) but I need contains for lazy typing purposes. I was searching the net, but the examples are always on so much different concept, than I have here. Can someone make example for this sql, how to make index please? the TextBox1.Text is inserted value of last name by user.

```
SELECT * FROM v_employees_intr 
where CONTAINS(NLSSORT(LAST_CZ, 'NLS_SORT = hungarian_ai'), NLSSORT('%" + TextBox1.Text + "%', 'NLS_SORT = hungarian_ai'))>0  
ORDER BY " + RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue.ToString() + " ASC"
```

How to create a Text index? I tried to

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON docs(text) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
```

Because [Oracle web site](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/ind.htm#CIHJAJF%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BJ.) says it is basic for `contains()`. But this error message pop out `ORA-02158: invalid CREATE INDEX option`. So I tried to add the ; on end like `IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;` and there then goes `ORA-00911: invalid character` error. Please can someone help me create index for my query?

Comment: What is the question? Do you need help to create an index? If so, what have you tried and what is the issue? Please clarify your question

Comment: Questions is, how to create index for my sql. Yes I need help with creating of an index. I did go through https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/ind.htm#CIHJAJFJ. Tried to CREATE INDEX myindex ON docs(text) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT as is stated on oracel web as basic for contains and even swap to CTXCAT instead of Contains, but without any succes. I am asking here for simplified explanation maybe sample code for my case. Thanks.

Comment: When you say "without any success" what actually happens? Please describe the behavior, including any error messages you get. Also please **edit your question** to clarify your question. Comments are hard to read

Comment: Eddited* Hope so it is clear now.

Answer (score 2):

You should try with:

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON v_employees_intr(LAST_CZ) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;
```

Comment: Please format the code, and explain why this solves OP's question. (maybe also read [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)